# QEMU ftp connection refused on linux guest but not in windows host (qemu blocking localhost connection??)

Tags: linux, debian, windows, qemu, ftp

I'm using QEMU to run debian linux on my windows machine. I setup a filezilla ftp server running on localhost in my windows. I can connect to the ftp server from my windows cmd

[image]

But i can't connect to ftp server in localhost from my debian linux in qemu

[image]

I can't connect to localhost, but strangely i can connect to website in internet

[image]

I don't understand, i can connect to internet but i can't connect to localhost? this gave me the impression that QEMU might be blocking localhost connection, but i'm not entirely sure whether this is true nor why.

I'm trying to use ftp to transfer file from my windows to my qemu and vice versa (because i tried other method to share file and no success).

Does anyone know how to fix this problem ??

Comment: This is not a Linux problem. You have questions on the emulator that is a Windows program.

Comment: Do not post images when plain text will do.

Comment: In windows, windows is localhost. In em, linux is localhost. no ftp-server in linux, no connection. localhost is a pure virtual interface.

Answer (score 0):

Right after I posted this question I found the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67520919/how-can-i-share-the-localhost-of-my-host-computer-with-a-qemu-image .

I mistakenly thought that the qemu localhost is the same as host localhost. The answer is no. Trying to connect to localhost in qemu will connect to localhost IN the qemu and not the localhost in the host machine. To connect to host localhost, qemu provided a special address for it, which was `10.0.2.2`

[image]

Comment: Do not post images when plain text will do.